# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k+m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k{m \choose k}\frac{1}{k+n+1}$.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I actually found this question in a calculus exercise, so I thought maybe it is an idea to convert an infinite sum to a Riemannian Integral.

But then, I realized that it was missing the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ and the $\frac{1}{n}$(which turns to $dx$ in the limit) I saw in most other types. Heck! it even had two limits in the form of $m$ and $n$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k+m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k{m \choose k}\frac{1}{k+n+1}$$

I then tried out at least making the $\frac{k}{n}$ part(which becomes $``x"$) and taking a $log$ on both sides(due to it being a factorial which can be converted into a sum of terms in a $log$) but then it became utter garbage since no clean expression came out.

I am currently back on square 1 now. Please help

Comment: You should accept an answer if it resolved your query to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k x^{k+m}=x^m (1-x)^n.$$ The value on the left side is thus:

$$\int_0^1 x^{m}(1-x)^n\,dx$$

But a change of variables $y=1-x$ gives that this integral is:

$$\int_0^1 y^n(1-y)^m\,dy$$
which is equal to the right side of your equation.

---

You can compute these values by induction. If $$I_{m,n}= \int_0^1 x^{m}(1-x)^n\,dx$$
then let $u=(1-x)^n, dv=x^mdx.$ Then $v=\frac1{m+1}x^{m+1}, du=-n(1-x)^{n-1}$ and:

$$I_{m,n}=\frac{n}{m+1}I_{m+1,n-1}$$

By induction, that is:

$$\begin{align}I_{m,n}&=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots 1}{(m+1)\cdots(m+n)}I_{m+n,0}\\&=\frac{1}{(m+n+1)\binom{m+n}{n}}\end{align}$$

Comment: +1, Nice method!

Comment: This is $\mathrm{B}(m+1,n+1)$, where $\mathrm{B}$ is the beta-function.

Comment: Another reminder that I need to revise combinatorics from class 11. Anyways, really elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

The decomposition of $\frac{n!}{x(x+1)\cdots (x+n)}$ into partial fractions is
$$\frac{n!}{x(x+1)\cdots (x+n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}}{x+k}$$

Now it's easy to see that both expressions equal
$$\frac{m! n!}{(m+n+1)!}$$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Yes, you are right. The partial fraction formula is OK, the final result missed the factor $m+n+1$.  Thanks, corrected that!